# Parcel: unable to marshal when going to another Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I get the `Parcel: unable to marshal value Articolo(barcode=5, qta=1)` error when i'm trying to navigate away from my Fragment to my Settings activity, that happend only when i've just added a new item to my database and only when i navigate then to the fragment with the recyclerView which show the items from database.

The optionsMenu where i initialize the action to navigate to settings in set in my MainActivity and looks like this:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            val navHostFragment =
                    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
            val navController = navHostFragment.navController
            navController.navigate(R.id.open_settingsActivity)
            return true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

As in my nav_graph for both fragments i created the action with same ID to navigate to the settings Activity.

Then in my SecondFragment which crash when i've added a new item to my database i have the following code and nothing else

```
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private val articoliViewModel: ArticoliViewModel
    get() = (activity as MainActivity).articoliViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
    val item: MenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search)
    item.isVisible = true
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    val adapter = ArticoliListAdapter()
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    articoliViewModel.articoli.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { articoli ->
        articoli.let { adapter.submitList(it) }
    }

    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnIndietro).setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment)
    }
}
```

My Articolo.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "articoli_letti_table")
data class Articolo(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
        var barcode: String,
        var qta: Int
        )
```

Comment: Add `Articolo` with question its better if you name classes in English that will more sense to all.

Comment: @ADM just updated the question with it

Comment: I do not see a `parcelable` or `Serializable` implementation for this class . have you missed it ?

Comment: @ADM no actually i doesn't have a parcelable or Serializable code in my code... that's the problem